# webView firebase

Tags: java, android-studio

Добрый день. Не так давно начал заниматься созданием приложений. Столкнулся с проблемой: после добавления через `firebase` аналитики Android Studio стала выдавать ошибки такого рода:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.summer.wm, PID: 3947
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.summer.wm/com.example.summer.wm.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.summer.wm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: У вас NPE при попытке загрузить рекламу в AdView кое null. Это дословный перевод ошибки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ,Благодарю. та проблема ушла теперь появилась такая.  14:07:02 Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 4s 797ms
В Grable идти нужно?

Comment: Там, по идее, должна быть ещё инфа, прочитав которую можно узнать что за проблема и как её решить. Попробуйте ещё вот так добавить больше инфы в выдачу градла: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21674403/3212712